# Cannot sudo with Debian 10

Tags: debian, sudo

I have installed Debian 10 on Dell Inspiron with an AMD processor.  I am using the KDE Plasma desktop.  When I try

```
sudo dpkg  -i ./palemoon_28.6.1+repack-2_amd64.deb
```

I get

```
[sudo] password for peter: 
peter is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported.
```

I logged in as root and entered

```
/usr/sbin/adduser peter
```

This returned

adduser: The user `peter' already exists.

I then tried the following as root

```
chmod 0440 /etc/sudoers
```

When I try to sudo, in the peter account, I still get

```
peter is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported.
```

I then try the following as root

```
sudo usermod -aG sudo,adm peter
```

Still get the same reslt when I try to sudo from the peter account.

Opening a new terminal, for the peter account, does not change anything.

Edit

```
cat /etc/sudoers
root@debian:/home/peter/Downloads# cat /etc/sudoers
#
# This file MUST be edited with the 'visudo' command as root.
#
# Please consider adding local content in /etc/sudoers.d/ instead of
# directly modifying this file.
#
# See the man page for details on how to write a sudoers file.
#
Defaults        env_reset
Defaults        mail_badpass
Defaults        secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:    /usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"

# Host alias specification

# User alias specification

# Cmnd alias specification

# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# See sudoers(5) for more information on "#include" directives:

#includedir /etc/sudoers.d


root@debian:/home/peter/Downloads# id peter
uid=1000(peter) gid=1000(peter)   groups=1000(peter),4(adm),24(cdrom),25(floppy),27(sudo),29(audio),30(dip),44(video),46(plugdev),109(netdev),112(bluetooth),116(lpadmin),117(scanner)
```

Comment: What's in /etc/sudoers? What groups is your user in?

Comment: The problem is sudo use its own settings to decide whether a user can run a command.

Comment: Add the output of `cat /etc/sudoers` and `id peter` to your question. Also, `/etc/sudoers` already has 440 permissions so there's no need to run `chmod` on it.

Comment: Thank you for your replies.  I have edited my question to include the output of "cat /etc/sudoers" and "id peter"

Comment: Try `newgrp sudo` in that new window, then the sudo command.

Comment: I know you’ve already answered your own question, but did you log out and back into peter after adding that ID to the `sudo` group? Groups don’t take effect until that user logs in again. A full login, not just opening a new terminal.

Answer (score 0):

As root, I created a file

```
vi /etc/sudoers.d/peter
```

and added

```
peter    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

I can now sudo from the peter account.